# How does ruby on rails evaluate resources names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried naming my resources in `routes.rb` a little creatively and ruby on rails picked on it every time.

How does it evaluate the singular form of the plurals I have used, as below.

```
resources :galaxies

$ rake routes
new_galaxy GET    /galaxies/new(.:format)                           galaxies#new
```

Also

```
resources :addresses

$ rake routes
new_address GET    /addresses/new(.:format)                          addresses#new
```

and it knows the plural of `fish` is `fish` !!

```
resources :fish

$ rake routes
new_fish GET    /fish/new(.:format)                               fish#new
```

How does it pick on these ? Is it hardcoded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, rules for the english language are [hardcoded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d30586211b41e018869a1a3f4e3af778a31591db/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb).

"fish" in particular:

```
inflect.uncountable(%w(equipment information rice money species series fish sheep jeans police))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and other things have the plural right in the file name ;)